# Neo4jRB: Searching through all associations?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Consider this simple setup:

```
class Person
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name, type: String

  has_many :out, :follows, model_class: Person, rel_class: Friendship
  has_many :in, :followed_by, model_class: Person, rel_class: Friendship
end

class Friendship
  include Neo4j::ActiveRel

  property :key, type: String

  type 'friendship'
  from_class Person
  to_class Person
end
```

How would I search through all `Friendship`s for those matching a condition? (e.g. `Friendship`s of a certain key).

In an email, Brian Underwood points me to this snippet:

```
ModelClass.association_name(:node_var, :rel_var).where("rel_var = 'some_condition'")
```

I've tried playing around with it, but don't understand. Is `ModelClass` an `ActiveNode` or `ActiveRel` instance? What  is `:node_var` and `:rel_var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for every friendship that has a specific `key` property, you'd do that like this:

```
Person.all.follows.rel_where(key: your_key_var)
# OR
Person.all.follows(:f, :r).where('r.key = {key}').params(key: your_key_var)
```

These will both generate `MATCH (p:Person)-[r:friends]->(f:Person)`, more or less, with the first example using auto-defined node identifiers and the second using `f` for the destination Friend node and `r` for the relationship, as given by the `:f, :r` arguments. After that, a `to_a` will return the friend at the END of the chain or you can call `pluck` with either `:f` or `:r` to return the given objects.

The `model_class` option always describes the NODE class on the other side of the association. In Brian's example, `node_var` and `rel_var` are generic names for the identifiers Cypher will use in the statement that it creates.

Comment: Great, looking at the generated query, those parameters make a lot more sense. Thank you.